# Activities shows Zoom twice

Tags: launcher

I have installed a new version of Zoom from their website. Now when I go SuperKey/Zoom I see two icons.
How to remedy this, please.
Thanks. - Erny

Comment: Uninstall the one you're not going to use anymore. Or are you asking how to figure that out?

Comment: if you installed the first time using snap then sudo snap remove zoom-client will remove the snap package..

Comment: I ran "sudo snap remove zoom-client. One icon is gone. one remained. I went into Ubuntu Software, searched for Zoom, clicked 'remove'. Now both are gone. Thank you.